# (WCF) How to get the username of the logged on client inside my service?

Tags: wcf, authentication

I have a custom password validator, an extension from `System.IdentityModel.Selectors.UserNamePasswordValidator`. How can I get the username though from within the service?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you want just the username:

```
OperationContext.Current.ServiceSecurityContext.PrimaryIdentity.Name
```

If you want both the username and password, Rory Primrose explains it in his article [WCF Security: Getting the password of the user](http://www.neovolve.com/2008/04/07/wcf-security-getting-the-password-of-the-user/)

Comment: @MichaelS.Miller Try: http://www.neovolve.com/2008/04/07/wcf-security-getting-the-password-of-the-user/